# Is there an easy way to create a "IntensitySquaredCentroid" using ComponentMeasurements?

Tags: image-processing

One of the options in ComponentMeasurements is to compute a centroid based on the pixel values of some underlying image.  We can write:

```
ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents[image], image}, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]];
```

Is it possible, however, to have something like an intensity squared or cubed centroid?

Comment: Why not just pass `Image[ImageData[image]^3]` to `ComponentMeasurements`?

Comment: @nikie, or `ImageApply[#^3 &, image]` or even `ImageAdjust[image, {0,0,3}]`. I suggest you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Turning the comments into an answer. Why not just pass `Image[ImageData[image]^3]` or `ImageApply[#^3 &, image]` or even `ImageAdjust[image, {0,0,3}]` to [`ComponentMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html)?